# Check which word is a real one and common used

Tags: keyword, resource-cleanup

I have a database with 70k keywords build from my data. The problem is, that some (10-15%) of the words are not real common used keywords. How can I check which one are not real good words, so I can clean my table? Has onyone some idea?

Comment: You would need some type of dictionary or source containing what you consider to be legitimate or common words. As that is highly subjective, you may need to create the source.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary type tool that has an API so you can compare the words in your database to the words in the dictionary tools database.

EDIT:  
Once such tool you might find helpful is [dictionary.com's API](http://developer.dictionary.com/)

You might also want to look for the following on Linux systems:

```
/usr/share/dict/ 
/var/lib/dict/
```

Comment: Hi, well its easy, but do you have some dictionary type tool with api?

Comment: What OS are you using and what language do you want the API to use?

Comment: I am using linux/ubuntu and need the programming language should not be the problem. An Api should be delivered in XML or JSON.

Comment: You should be able to use the dictionary files on ubuntu as I mentioned in my answer. The dictionary.com API uses XML but limits you to 1K lookups per day with the free API access, so this doesn't seem like a good way to go. So it looks to me like you should use either the Linux dictionary files or do some research of your own to find on online dictionary that meets your XML/JSON lookup needs.

Comment: Hi, this with the linux is great. i have in /usr/share/dict/ 4 files: american-english, british-english, ngerman, ogerman . What is the different ce between the german files and how to put other languages there?

Comment: That I don't know. Those files are often used by a program called `aspell` so you might do some research into that program and see about obtaining other dictionaries. Another thought is that you can probably automate MS Word using VBA to get access to it's built in dictionary. But if you are going to use the solution provided in my answer I would appreciate it if you would accept the answer. When you accept an answer the person who provided the solution you chose gets some reputation points.